# Can someone help me with this predicate question?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Ok, first and foremost:
`V` represents `OR`.
`^` represents `AND`.
`=>` for condional.

Just wanted to point that out since I don't have the actual symbols on my keyboard and don't know how to get them.

I was doing some revision on `predicates` and came accross this question:

```
Show that:
[ (p => q)^(q => r) ] => (p => r) = 1
```

I changed the equation to this:

```
[ (p ^ -q) V (q ^ -r) ] V (-p V r) = 1
```

But what do I do with the 1?
How does the one relate to the equation?

I don't remember coming accross this in my lectures.

Comment: I think this is notation ambiguity:  I think you mean:

[ (p => q)^(q => r) ] => [(p => r) = 1] so 

[ (p ^ -q) V (q ^ -r) ] V [(-p V r) = 1].  I *think*.

Comment: ...or...   X = 1 is just the equivalent of say "X is true" which is the same as saying X.  So in essence you can "drop" the "= 1".

Comment: @fleablood - Ahh right. So the "=1" means "is true".

Comment: I *assume* so.  That's my memory of the notation from back when the dinosaurs scribbled with sticks.

Comment: @fleablood - Haha that makes sense. I should have spotted that. I assumed it meant it all equaled the integer 1. Thanks :)

Comment: That should be an axiomatic rule:  (X = 1) = X and (X = 0) = -X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you realized, $1$ is often used to denote $true$, and $0$ denotes $false$. This isn't arbitrary, because $x \land y = x \times y$ with real arithmetic! Additionally, we use bitmasks with $1$ denoting presence of some property and $0$ denoting absence.